# how to manually enter data in firebase dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement an "articles" section in my firebase database, how can I manually enter in the data? I want it set up like this but have only done it through code.

[image]

Comment: Have you visited the database interface from console.firebase.google.com?

Answer (score 2):

hover your click on a brach key (for example feed), then a `+` icon will appear. then you can create the name of the new branch and the value of the keys (that can be other json's)

[image: screenshot taken adding values manually to a Firebase Realtime-Database]